# Need to show data in weeks between selected timeframe

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to show the data broken down in weeks if you choose the start date and end date.   I have to show in a stacked column chart. I am trying to show the values if you choose for example last month i need to show it by weeks for example

```
week  user name total approved first approved last aprovedDate totalitemsAdded
----- --------- -------------- -------------- ---------------- ---------------
week1 XYZ       3              10/01/2012     10/05/2012       5
week2 XYZ       5              etc            etc              etc
week3
```

Below is the code and the result  i am getting now .

Current Results

```
UserName TotalApproved FirstApprovedDate       LastApprovedDate        TotalItemsAdded
-------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------
XYZ      9             2011-11-19 16:56:49.960 2011-11-19 18:18:20.783 2
```

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '10/1/2012 '
SET @EndDate = '10/31/2012'

;with Items as(
       SELECT
              UserName = Profile.Description,
              TotalItems = COUNT(TransactionID),
              FirstAddedDate = MIN(UTCDate),
              LastAddedDate = MAX(UTCDate)
       FROM Transactiondatabase.dbo.transaction
                JOIN Biography.dbo.Profile ON transaction.ProfileId = Profile.ProfileID
       WHERE 
              Data like '%ItemAdded%'
                AND UTCDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate)
       GROUP BY
              Profile.Description 
)

,
Approved as
(
       SELECT 
              UserName = Profile.Description,
              TotalApproved = COUNT(TransactionID),
              FirstApprovedDate = MIN(UTCDate),--Demo
              LastApprovedDate = MAX(UTCDate)                 
       FROM Transactiondatabase..transaction
                JOIN Biography.dbo.Profile ON transaction.ProfileId = Profile.ProfileID
       WHERE 
              Data like '%Approved%'
                AND UTCDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate)
       GROUP BY
                Profile.Description
)

Select Distinct Approved.*, TotalItemssAdded = sum(distinct Items.TotalItems)
from Items, Approved  
Group by Approved.UserName, Approved.FirstApprovedDate, Approved.LastApprovedDate, Approved.TotalApproved
using ssrs 2005
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find:

```
DATEPART( WEEK, UTCDate )
```

helpful. As in:

```
SELECT FirstApprovedWeek = DATEPART( WEEK, UTCDATE ) FROM table
```

See [MSDN - DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) for more details and usage options.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. But this will give only a week of the year.

Comment: @user3096831 - Yes, but you can group on the week of the year and then use MIN, MAX to get the start/end of the week.